# How to loop through results from a Promise to pass it to React components

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise

I am thinking this is because I need to learn more about `Async` and `Promises` in `JS`
But so I have some `Async API` that returns some people's info, something like this in the structure of it shows in Chrome's Console. I copied the first guy:

```
Promise {<fulfilled>: Array(12)}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Array(12)
0:
id: "ec6eee79-5ab8-44a9-8fbf-35668ec3a668"
name: "John Travolta"
__proto__: Object
```

So I wrote a simple component to loop through them for now, but clearly it is not the right way. I had to comment out the part that is failing. but that's the kind of thing I am hoping to accomplish.
So how should I change this?

```
const UserComponent = (props) => {
  const results = API.getSomePeopleInfo().then((response) => {
    const result = Promise.resolve(response.data);
    console.log("so data was this: ", result);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>A user</h1>
      {/*{results.map((r) => (*/}
      {/*  <li>{r.name}</li>*/}
      {/*))}*/}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You have to check that result has a content before using it, soomething like `result && result.map(...)`.

Comment: ok but that just makes sure it won't crash.. in my example I do have data but the way I am accessing it is wrong

Comment: Yes, because your results content come from a async function, by the time you reach your html code, results doesn't have nothing. You should make it a variable state and update it with the results.

Comment: `Promise.resolve()` does not 'resolve' a promise you give it, it returns a new promise in resolved status. You don't need it in your code. Almost no one needs it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a async function, that doesn't resolve instantly, it means that when you reach the render method, result's won't have data. You could just make it a state variable and update it in the then callback:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const UserComponent = (props) => {
  // Using react with hooks
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  API.getSomePeopleInfo().then((response) => {
    const peoples = response.data;
    setResults(peoples)
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>A user</h1>
      {/*{results && results.map((r) => (*/}
      {/*  <li>{r.name}</li>*/}
      {/*))}*/}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Just learning the async way

Comment: Should put the http request inside useEffect, otherwise it will send it on every re-render